# using autocompleteextender without webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, autocomplete, n-tier-architecture, autocompleteextender

> Is it possible to use autocomplete extender without using
>   webservice..
>           and also am working with 3tier architechture..i could retrieve one column
>           but i could not return the string separately..